# Proxy object with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, proxy-pattern

I'm trying to implement proxy pattern with swift to create an configuration object for my custom object inherited from NSObject. It would be something like UIAppearance for UIView. But I don't understand how to do method call forwarding, which I would do in objective-c with `forwardInvocation:` method and [NSInvocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/) class.

If someone faced with such kind of problem, and have a solution, I would be thankful to hear.
Thanks in advance.